# Where have my safari, App Store, iTunes Store, and Siri gone?

Tags: iphone

I was trying to manage storage and deleting pictures to clear up space. I went back to my home screen and noticed something was different. Well it seems my Safari icon is gone. Also iTunes and my AppStore is nowhere to be found. It's been this way for two weeks and I've been tryin to search all through my phone to find em. When I go to settings I can't find any if them either. I thought about askin Siri to bring em up for me but she seems to be gone also!! And it comes up some voice control thing! Can anyone help?! How can I get them back?

Comment: Have you checked if restrictions are enabled?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your restrictions were turned on somehow. Try the following:

1. Open Settings
2. Tap General
3. Scroll down to Restrictions and see if it says it's On
4. If it is, when you tap it, it will ask for a "Restrictions Passcode". If you don't remember setting this then just try your unlock code or SIM PIN.
5. You'll probably notice that the toggles for Safari and the others are set to off. If you don't want these restrictions in place then just tap "Disable Restrictions" at the top of that view.
6. You'll be asked to enter that passcode one last time to disable the restrictions

And that's it! You should now be able to access everything again!

If you can't, there's another possibility that the device is being managed with a provisioning profile so if the above doesn't work, leave a comment and let me know. :)

Comment: If this does not work, just back it up and then restore it.

Comment: @SuryanIsaac, back up and restore is an older method which, in most cases, wastes time and doesn't do much. Settings > General > Reset > Reset All Settings is faster and more likely to fix issues. Here, whatever preference is causing Springboard to hide the app icons would most likely be backed up and restored too.